# Central css file

Tags: html, css

is it possible to have one central CSS File for recurrent changes? I have the .css1 where i have ...div{text-align:left}... and .css2 where i have ...form{margin:0;}...
What i need is a .css3 where i have div{text-align:left}  form{margin:0;}
 and if i make changes in .css3 like div{text-align:right}, it will overwrite the value in the correspondings file .css1. Purpose is that the Administrator do not always have to go through the whole css files to make minor changes. 
Thank you in advance for your help

Aline

Comment: Yeah put the "central css file" changes in a file, and link it in the `<head>` after the rest of the CSS files. Whenever a CSS file is called after another CSS file, the rules in the last CSS file will take precedence - assuming that file uses the same or higher CSS specificity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to import the css files in the correct order. If you have text-align: left in the first css and text-align: right in the second one, the first sentence will be overwritten by the second.

If not, you can always use !important in the last css like this:

```
text-align: right !important;
```